# Set PageLayout Object by Page Layout Name

Tags: 2010, development, publishing-page

I have code as part of an event receiver that creates a publishing page upon feature activation. That publishing page is built on a page layout that is deployed as part of that same feature.

The `pages.Add` method of the `PublishingPage` object requires a `PageLayout` object of the layout you wish to have the page created with. I'm currently using the following code to identify and set the `PageLayout` object.

```
PublishingWeb activePublishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
PublishingPageCollection pages = activePublishingWeb.GetPublishingPages();
PageLayout customLayout = null;
foreach (PageLayout layout in activePublishingWeb.GetAvailablePageLayouts())
{
    if (layout.Name.Equals("MyLayout.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        customLayout = layout;
        break;
    }
}
```

This method of grabbing all of the page layouts and iterating through them works, but it seems rather inefficient. Is there a better way to specifically target a page layout using a name or a URL? I know you can filter the PageLayout return by associated content type, but that still gives me a collection of all Welcome Pages, not just my custom one.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

---

With Per's suggestion below, here's the new code for anyone that may stumble upon this thread in the future:

```
SPFile customLayoutFile = web.GetFile("_catalogs/masterpage/MyLayout.aspx");
SPListItem customLayoutItem = customLayoutFile.Item;
PageLayout customLayout = new PageLayout(customLayoutItem);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the url of the PageLayout you can use [SPWeb.GetFile(url)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms476063.aspx) to get the corresponding SPFile and the use the [PageLayout constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.pagelayout.pagelayout.aspx) on the [Item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfile.item.aspx) property of that SPFile

Comment: That did it; thank you Sir! Original post updated with new solution.